# bootstrap slideshow that shows sentences rather than pictures

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a slideshow without including pictures in it, just like
[this website](http://www.pearanalytics.com/). See how sentences are moving inside the hero unit?

Answer (score 0):

View their [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) but you can place virtually anything inside their `item` div. You just need to set the appropriate CSS

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <p>Your text here</p>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
         ...
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it didn't work...the text will still come out under the hero unit..wheres i want it to be on top of it